# Why google font 'Roboto' still looks fat after putting weight 100?

Tags: html, css, fonts

```
<head>
   <title>Privacy Policy</title>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">



<h2>Brief summary of our Privacy Policy</h2>

    <div class="text">

        <p>We value your privacy.</p>

            <h3>General</h3>
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
  background-color: black;
  font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  color: #fffffe;
  font-size: 20pt;
  letter-spacing: 0.2pt;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h2 {
  color: #fffffe;
  font-size: 40pt;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

1st part of the picture is what my result looks like.
2nd part is where I need to get.
3rd part is from google fonts.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Google Web Fonts only load the weight 400.

You need to specify in the URL the others weights you want by appending them after a colon.

So for your case the url should be :

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,400" rel="stylesheet">
```

Source : https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started

Answer (score 5):

You need to select the `100` font weight.

```css
h2 {
  color: #fffffe;
  font-size: 40pt;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1 {
  color: #fffffe;
  font-size: 20pt;
  letter-spacing: 0.2pt;
  font-weight: 400;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,400" rel="stylesheet">
<h1>this is an h1</h1>
<h2>Brief summary of our Privacy Policy</h2>
```

Answer (score 3):

Time to learn a thing about how fonts and CSS work together.

Single font files (so, on modern computers that's individual `ttf` and `otf` files, for the web that also includes `woff` and `woff2` files) encode a *single* weight. A font like "Roboto-Regular" only contains one weight of glyphs, and so if CSS loads just that font, you can change `font-weight` as much as you want but it'll do nothing, because you haven't told the CSS engine what to do. It just keeps using the same font.

(2018 edit: OpenType now supports variable fonts, meaning that if the font has an `fvar` table it can be used to render a full spectrum of weights/variation for a typeface. Browser-support for this is still being figured out as of this edit, so that doesn't change the rest of the answer. Yet)

Instead, you need to tell the CSS engine that you need multiple, different, fonts for different weights. Google fonts does this for you if you request different weights (as noted in the other answers) but what really happens is that Google fonts generate CSS like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url(roboto-regular.woff) format('WOFF')
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url(roboto-light.woff) format('WOFF')
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url(roboto-thin.woff) format('WOFF')
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url(roboto-ultra-thin.woff) format('WOFF')
}

etc.
```

And because of that, your browser's CSS engine now knows that why you say `font-weight: 100`, it needs to just that `robot-ultra-thin` font instead of the regular font.

"But why does this work for things like `Times`?"

Good question: because system fonts are already large collections of different font files. Note that when you're using CSS, you ask for a `font-family`. The "family" part is important: you are not asking for individual fonts, you're asking for an entire font family, and by default from that family you're asking for the style:normal, weight:normal version. Your OS is perfectly capable of finding the right single font file to hand to your browser's CSS engine for that purpose, and so when you as for `font-family: Times` your brower's actually loading `Times-regular.ttf` or something similar.

But if a font family doesn't have as many weighs as there are CSS weights, then no amount of saying "weight:100" is going to make a font-family without an ultra thin font look ultra thin. If the font resource doesn't exist (either because it literally doesn't exist, or because you forgot to teach CSS what font file you need loaded for a weight:100) the result is undefined, albeit predictable (the browser will end up using the closest matching font it *does* know about) and you should not be using CSS with undefined behaviour. You're on the hook to make sure it's defined =)